# video4linux2 command for mac osx with isight

Tags: macos, isight

So I was just wondering is there anything like this on a mac with the isight, where you can record video using the isight via the command line? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux 'ffmpeg' uses the '[video4linux2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux)' capture API, and on Windows there is a version called 'video4windows.' A version of this API does not exist for the Mac.

---

If you wish to record video from your iSight camera from the commandline, use this free software instead:

**[Wacaw - Webcam Tools for Mac OS X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcam-tools/files/latest/download)**

---

Here is an example of its usage.

- Step 1) **See what video hardware is present**:

> wacaw -L

- Step 2) **Capture** your video to file. On my MacBook, it reports my internal iSight camera as a USB device of ID '2' with an input of ID '0'. Here's how it looks for my MacBook. The 'video-device' may differ for your computer, and you might also be able to omit the '--video-input 0' section:

> wacaw  --video --video-device 2 --video-input 0 --duration 3 --VGA  ~/MyMovie

---

Another alternative is to install Linux, and 'isight-firmware-tools', on your Mac hardware. There are details on using on [this blog](http://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/use-your-macs-isight-on-ubuntu), though I did not test them. Unlike the Wacaw method above, you would have to boot into an entirely different OS to use this second alternative.

Hope this helps!